# How to upload a custom module

Tags: magento2

I'm having problems uploading a new module that i have created. I upload all the files to the right place then I get a message asking me to setup:upgrade because of the new module and the re compile.

After doing this I can't access the site. When I run grunt clean etc... It starts coming up with loads of errors. So what I would like to know is what order and what commands do I need to run to install the new module correctly?

Am I also right in calling them modules? The module I created was called Magento_SearchSlide.

Version Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Did you load it via composer, or manually into app/code?

Run from the command line:

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

By default, the module should not be enabled from adding your files. You can do that using:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_SearchSlide
```

This will create tb tables for you, and probably ask you to run setup:upgrade.

Of course you can disable it the same way:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_SearchSlide
```

To remove any created db tables you need to use

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall Magento_SearchSlide
```

Comment: I did it manually into app/code

Comment: How did you create your module without having it installed in a magento2 environment? I usually setup my module with the basics first, so magento2 sees it, then it work on it until its finished. So it is basically installed from the get go.

Comment: I just created all files then uploaded to app/ Is this not the right way of doing? What are the basics?

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials how to go about it, but I personally develop in a working test store. I create my module folder and the basic files first for the module to be 'seen' by magento. From there on I develop step by step, knowing that it works every step of the way. And that way I see a mistake when I made it, not after I have written the whole module.

Comment: I done what you said above but as soon as I do a grunt clean I get the following error: >>   There are no commands defined in the "dev:source-theme" namespace.
>> Exited with code: 1.
Warning: Task "exec:atharna" failed. Use --force to continue.  Do you know what this relates to?

Comment: Did you run `php magento setup:upgrade`? And, after you enabled the module did you check in `app/etc/env.php` to make sure it's enabled?

Comment: Why would you run grunt clean? It has not bearing on uploading or enabling a module! You should maybe close this ticket and ask the question in regards to grunt clean, as this has nothing to do with modules.